# How To Declare A Variable That Hasn't Rendered Yet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project that uses jQuery. And I am trying to convert this script to Javascript. I had the following line on that script.

```
var a = $("#myImage");
```

I changed it to

```
var a = document.getElementById("myImage");
```

but script is not working because my page hasn't loaded yet when this happens. I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<body onload="var a = document.getElementById("myImage");">
</body>
```

`onload="var a = document.getElementById("myImage");"` runs when the content is fully loaded. When the body is completely loaded then `var a = document.getElementById("myImage");` will run.

Comment: It worked. Tks for your time for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the script once the page loads.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  // .... Add your script here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include a listener on the `document` object to wait for the DOM to be loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  var a = document.getElementById("myImage");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

       var a = document.getElementById("myImage");
       //Rest code here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, for instance:

1. Place corresponding `<script>` tag before closing `</body>` tag.
2. Start doing things [when document is loaded using a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/9430588).

Personally, I prefer the 1st option much more since it works more stably according to my experience.